# json.net serialize additonal condition properties on a class inheriting from List<T>

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a collection class that inherits from `List<T>`

```
public class TestCollection : List<Test>
{
   public virtual String SomeTestingDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Json.NET will serialize an array of test objects but leaves off the `SomeTestingDetail` property.

Is there a way to force this property to be serialized as well?

Comment: Hint: what would you expect the JSON for that to look like?

Comment: @Chris, I would expect it to contain one addition field. {"$id": 1, MyAdditionalField: "here", "$values":[ <collection elements >]}. There is no reason to think it would make significant change. At least in version of JSON.NET I use now, with my current settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON.net serializer converts a List into an array, and any properties directly in a collection will be ignored. From the Json.Net site "Because JSON arrays only support a range of values and not properties, any additional properties and fields declared on .NET collections are not serialized. " A better way would be to use a class which the string property and a property which holds the list of items.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Comment: I did not see that in the documentation.  Thanks for pointing it out.